# Attempt by security transparent method Kigg.Web.jQueryScriptManager.OnInit

Tags: asp.net, kigg

I am trying to configure Kigg project on my machine and i am getting this error.

> Attempt by security transparent method 'Kigg.Web.jQueryScriptManager.OnInit(System.EventArgs)' to access
>   LinkDemand protected method
>   'Kigg.Web.jQueryScriptManager.get_Current()' failed.  Methods must be
>   security critical or security safe-critical to satisfy a LinkDemand.

Can someone please help me to resolve this error.

> **StackTrace**
>
> at Kigg.Web.jQueryScriptManager.OnInit(EventArgs e) in D:\EDrive\My
>   WebSites\MyUpdates\MyUpdates\Source\Web\Controls\jQueryScriptManager.cs:line
>   111    at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: this problems appears if we convert the project to run against .NET 4. with 3.5 it runs fine except i m finding crashes on each Html.RenderAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this attribute to your class `[SecuritySafeCritical]`

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997445.aspx) or [here](http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2009/05/28/introduction-to-security-transparency-in-net-4/)