# PayPal Core SDK with Medium Trust in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, paypal

Recently our Web hosting provider moved to a medium trust level for all shared ASP.NET site hosting. As a result, we're having some issues completing transactions via PayPal's REST API. Specifically, a SecurityException exception is being thrown with the following stack trace:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'PayPal.UserAgentHeader.get_OperatingSystemFriendlyName()' to access security critical method 'System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(System.String)' failed.

Assembly 'PayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.
```

Does any know what change(s) need to be made?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252500/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-to-access-security-critical-method-failed